# Find out the resource group of the storage account of cloud shell

Tags: azure, azure-storage-account, azure-cloud-shell

So I know that there is a storage account behind Azure Cloud Shell. How can I find out which storage account it is and most important which resource group is my Cloud Shell storage account belongs to?

Answer (score 1):

When you use basic settings and select only a subscription, Cloud Shell creates three resources on your behalf in the supported region that's nearest to you:

- Resource group: `cloud-shell-storage-[region]`
- Storage account: `cs[uniqueGuid]`
- File share: `cs-[user]-[domain]-com-[uniqueGuid]`

Storage accounts that you create in Cloud Shell are **tagged** with `ms-resource-usage:azure-cloud-shell`.

[image]

Comment: maybe I am in a big company and many of my colleagues use cloud shell too. How can I find out which uniqueGuid is for myself?

Comment: Then create a file in your instance of cloud shell then you can search the file share to find the storage account associated.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the above shared Requirement, we have created the below PowerShell script which will pull the cloud shell storage accounts & their respective resource groups.

We have tested the below script in our local environment which is working fine.

**Here is the PowerShell Script :**

```
Connect-AzAccount

$strglist=Get-AzStorageAccount ##pulling the storageaccounts in that particular subscription that you have connected to.

foreach( $item in $strglist){

    if( ($item.StorageAccountName -like 'cs*') -and  ($item.ResourceGroupName -like 'cloud-shell-storage*'))
    {
        Write-Host $item.StorageAccountName,$item.ResourceGroupName
    }
}
```

***Note*** :

All the cloud Shell storage accounts will have name start with 'cs' & respective resource groups will be with 'cloud-shell-storage' so we have used the `-like` operator & `wildcards` to pull the list of storage accounts.

**Here is the sample output for reference:**

[image]